# Access key pairs in a macOS keychain from the commandline

Tags: macos, command-line, security, keychain

I created a key pair in like this:

`security create-keypair -a dsa -s 4096 FooBar`

Now I want to access this key from to the command line to actually use it (in .pem format if possible). However, `security` doesn't have a `find-keypair`option, and I couldn't get any of the other `find_...` subcommands to work. Is there a way to do this?

#### Edit:

For now I found an (inconvenient) workaround:

1. First, manually create a "secure note" in keychain access, whose contents is the the private key.
2. Use the following abomination: `security find-generic-password -w -s "$SecureNoteName" | xxd -p -r | plutil -extract "NOTE" xml1 -o - - | xmllint --xpath '//string/text()' -`

So it seems I first have to fight the keychain to get its contents, and then I have to fight the plist to get the value... Parsing the plist could be simplified with the `defaults` command, but I wanted to avoid writing the key to a temp file, and I couldn't get defaults to read from stdin.

Comment: try `man security` and `man security create-keypair`. (man gives you a lot of info about a command.)

Comment: Did you read the question?

Comment: I did. You didn't specify whether you'd checked the manpage.

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding command to retrieve keys is `security find-key` -- at least there is one in 2023 macOS 13.4 Ventura.
Based on your sample you may fetch the private key using `security find-key -t private -l FooBar`.

The name you provided initially became a label and your command created a pair consisting of type private and public.

The output needs further updates before useful for, e.g. ssh.

```
keychain: "/Users/xyz/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
version: 512
class: 0x00000010 
attributes:
    0x00000000 <uint32>=0x00000010 
    0x00000001 <blob>="FooBar"
```